# what is the sum of $\sum_{k=1}^T x^{2k}$?

Tags: calculus, power-series

what is the sum for the following series
$$
x^{2\cdot 1} + x^{2\cdot 2} + x^{2\cdot 3} \ldots + x^{2\cdot T}
$$

lower and upper bounds are also welcome.

Comment: Do you know how to sum a geometric series?  This is one.  What is the ratio of the terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a geometric series. You have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^T x^{2k}=\sum_{k=1}^T (x^2)^k=\frac{x^2-(x^2)^{T+1}}{1-x^2}=\frac{x^2-x^{2T+2}}{1-x^2}.
$$

Comment: Is there any way to simplify the final fraction any further? I'm not sure if difference of squares could be applied to do so.

Comment: $$(1-x^2) = (1+x)(1-x) $$